# Cache ASP.NET Ajax ScriptManager scripts in the browser

Tags: asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

i am using ScriptManager in my webpage. i am also using a lot of pagemethods in this page. When i look at the viewsource of the browser after the page has been rendered i find a lot of javascript which has been generated by the scriptmanager.

how can i browser cache all these scripts so that they are not loaded everytime the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

By default they are cached. If you analyze the HTTP headers for these files you will find the cache settings. try analyzing with firebug or any other tool you use. There is also an online service which will analyze it for you http://www.port80software.com/

Comment: Do you know how caching headers are generated for scriptmanager axd scripts? Based on file modified date?

Comment: @dragonfly I guess the axd handlers generates the `Last-Modified` date since the site is running.

Comment: Pretty good assumption :) However I run into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566543/why-google-chrome-does-not-cache-this-resource

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it securely.  The Event Validation mechanism would throw "Invalid Postback or Callback arguments: errors.

The hidden "__EVENTVALIDATION" variable changes from postback to postback, and even though you can disable it, it's not a good idea,

See [this article](http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/09/conditional-updatepanel-and-event.html) for more info.